# Groovy with block in Java

Tags: java, groovy

In groovy, there is a `with` block, which can be used to call methods on a object like this:

```
obj.with
{
   method1()
   method2()
}
```

where `method1,method2` are methods for object `obj`.

Is the same is possible in Java 7? I mean can we make some way to do this in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, something like this is not possible.

Comment: what's the problem with: `obj.method1();` and `obj.method2();` ?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" but [this article](http://java.dzone.com/news/getting-groovy-with-with) shows why Groovy has the `with` construct.  The OP just wants to know how to do something similar in Java (if such a thing can be done).

Comment: @RayToal `with` makes Groovy even less verbose than it already is. Java, in contrast, is a *very* verbose language. That said, `obj.method1();` and `obj.method2();` isn't really *that* verbose (IMHO). Another alternative to call methods on an object is by using reflection which is way more verbose as well as expensive and redundant.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything similar to `with` in Java 7. The closest you can do is use an [Initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) while instantiating an [`anonymous class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
       new Test() {
            {
                method1();
                method2();
            }
        };
```

which might not suit every case, as you can only use it for initialization.

Where `Test` is:

```
class Test{
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println(1);
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an anonymous class. It's a simple block of code.

Comment: @Opal new Test(){ ... is an anonymous class, please correct me

Comment: @Opal, Yes its a simple block but try to see where it is. Is it in the class Test, can you find it there?

Comment: Ok it is. I thought You meant `{ method1(); method2();}`

Comment: @Opal is your -1 still valid?

Comment: It's not. Unfortunately I can't remove it, till You edit the post somehow.

Comment: @Opal, There isn't much to edit, Its not a new trick I am pointing to, but you sure jump the gun.